# Angular controller is not working with nsPopover module

Tags: angularjs, nspopover

I am using `nsPopover` module of Angular to open `popover` to show a notification.

I have created a template for that `popover` and want to update some data, but `scope` does not update. I think there is some conflict between `controllers` because in this page I have multiple `controllers`.

Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('notification', ['header', 'nsPopover']);

app.controller('notificationCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var notifyItems = [];
    $http.get('/secure/notify').success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    $scope.testing = "Hello world";
    $scope.getNotification = function() {
        $scope.items = 0;
    };
}]);
```

This is my `popover` directive:

```
  <button ns-popover ns-popover-template="popover">Click Me</button>
```

This is my template:

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="popover">
  <ul>
  {{testing}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

The app is configured with multiple tasks and this is one of them. So that I am not able to give any Plunker link.

This is an example for [nspopover](http://nohros.com/nsPopover/).

Comment: Try using $scope.$apply to update the scope.

Comment: I am getting this error `$apply already in progress` after applying it

Comment: If I am writing my `code` in `nsPopover` of lib file, then it's working fine, but I do not want to write in lib file